# Configure RSpec to use the Capybara.javascript_driver for all request specs

Tags: ruby, rspec, capybara, acceptance-testing

Is it possible globally configure RSpec to use Capybara's (default or custom) JavaScript driver for all request specs? We sometimes forget to manually add `js: true` to every request spec and it's kind of annoying.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In spec_helper.rb, set the following:

```
  config.before(:each) do
    if example.metadata[:type] == :request
      Capybara.current_driver = :selenium # or equivalent javascript driver you are using
    else
      Capybara.use_default_driver # presumed to be :rack_test
    end
  end
```

Comment: That works, but I'd like to limit this to request specs. Of course I could put this line in every single request spec file, but I'd like to configure it globally. Kind of like you can include specific Modules for certain spec types.

Comment: is there a similar workaround for rspec 3?  "example" isn't defined now

Answer (score 8):

For later versions of capybara and rspec, it's important to check for type being "feature"

```
config.before(:each) do
  if [:request, :feature].include? example.metadata[:type]
    Capybara.current_driver = :poltergeist # or equivalent javascript driver you are using
  else
    Capybara.use_default_driver # presumed to be :rack_test
  end
end
```

or for RSpec 3 (pass `example` into the block)

```
config.before(:each) do |example|
  if [:request, :feature].include? example.metadata[:type]
    Capybara.current_driver = :poltergeist # or equivalent javascript driver you are using
  else
    Capybara.use_default_driver # presumed to be :rack_test
  end
end
```

Comment: If you are using RSpec >= 3, you will need to write the first line of this like `config.before(:each) do |example|` to get the same behavior. More via @joshua-muheim here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24571607/2948832

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this solution if you want to run all test cases at once.

[Rspec+Capybara optionally change JS driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18501574/rspeccapybara-optionally-change-js-driver/20638548#20638548)

Comment: Put the relevant info into the post.