# Why do I get "undefined method or variable 'example'" in RSpec 3.0?

Tags: rspec, capybara

After upgrading to RSpec 3.0, I got the following message:

```
 Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace
 NameError:
   undefined local variable or method `example' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::Anonymous:0x007f9ae985b548>
```

The message persisted even after reducing the spec to the following:

```
describe "" do
  it "" do
  end
end
```

I did notice capybara was near the top of the stack, as follows:

```
 # /Users/palfvin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@botmetrics/gems/capybara-2.1.0/lib/capybara/rspec.rb:20:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

in case that helps.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This error results from installing RSpec 3.0.0.beta while continuing to run Capybara 2.1.0. If you install Capybara 2.2.0.beta, the error will go away.

Comment: There doesn't appear to be a Capybara 2.2.0.beta, just 2.2.0. https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/releases

Also, there doesn't appear to be a RSpec 3.0.0.beta, just beta1 https://github.com/rspec/rspec/releases

If I update to the latest of both, I still see this error. Any ideas?

Comment: I just installed those versions and it worked fine for me, albeit having to struggle with getting nokogiri 1.6.1 to install on Mavericks. If you post your stacktrace in a separate question, I'll take a look.

Comment: if you're using capybara-screenshot, try removing it. Seems like it's not yet compatible with the latest version of these gems.

Comment: I had to revert back to `gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 2.14.2'` to get the current version of capybara-screenshot (0.3.16) to work.

Answer (score 22):

I had a similar problem with a `before` hook.

It seems that RSpec < 3 provided an `example` object in every hook, like this:

```
config.before(:each) do
  if example.metadata[:js] # <--- this fails!
    # do something
  end
end
```

In RSpec >= 3, you have to pass an explicit example parameter to the block:

```
config.before(:each) do |example| # <--- see here!
  if example.metadata[:js]
    # do something
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

For some unrelated reasons I couldn't upgrade Capybara, so I use this monkey patch (add in a file in spec/support):

```
module Capybara
  module DSL
    def example
      RSpec.current_example
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error, not in Capybara, but in my specs. I did a find and replace of `example.` to `RSpec.current_example.` and it works now. Seems `example` is now `RSpec.current_example`.

Answer (score 1):

These worked form me using Ruby2/Rails4/RSpec3.0.0.beta and Capybara2.2.0.beta: 
ruby 2.0.0p353 (2013-11-22 revision 43784) [x86_64-linux]

- Gemfile

  `...
  gem 'rails', '4.0.1'
  group :development, :test do
     gem 'rspec-rails','~>3.0.0.beta' 
     gem 'factory_girl_rails' 
  end`

  group :test do
     gem 'faker'
     gem 'capybara', '>=2.2.0.beta'
     gem 'guard-rspec'
     gem 'launchy'
  end
- put Capybara specs in spec/features, not spec/requests.
- Tag all the example groups in which you want to use Capybara with:

  ```
  describe "Users", :type => :feature do
    ...
  end
  ```
- Add the following line to the spec_helper.rb:

  `require 'capybara/rspec'`

  and add the DSL to the RSpec.config block

  RSpec.configure do |config| block
  ...
  config.include Capybara::DSL